# Flash Flasks messages with a list of categories to HTML5 jinja2 template

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, flash-message

The idea is to use an advanced multiform, where i want to target the flash messages.

It is possible to specify categories 'a', 'b' in flask writing a line for each category and using the category argument.

This generates a bit of redundant code, so, would like to know if it is possible to send a list in category argument and filter it instead.

One way of doing this is using a for in Python and for each n desired categories resend the flash n times, it would be better to simply send one flash with all desired categories.

Using in flask the categories like so: 
 **using python**

```
@app.route('/')
def app_session():
    flash('This is a flash message with category a', 'a')
    flash('This is a flash with category b', 'b')
    return render_template('template.html')
```

**using HTML5 and jinja2**

```
<p>
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(category_filter=["a"]) %}
        {% if messages %}
            <ul class=flashes>
                {% for message in messages %}
                    <li>{{ message }}</li>                              
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
</p>
```

Now an idea is to:

```
#in python
flash('This is a flash message with categories a and c ', ['a','c'])
#in both html5 jinjas
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages(category_filter=["c"]) %}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could monkey patch `flask.flash`:

```
from flask import flash

def flash_categories(message, categories=['message']):
    for category in categories:
        flash(message, category=category)


import flask
flask.flash = flash_categories
```